# How to redirect non-authenticated users to login view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-authentication

I'm making an application which requires a user and password for access. Every user should face the login view. Currently, writing the URL manually, I can access all the routes without login. What I want is to redirect every unauthenticated user to the login view, so that they can't see anything else until they log in.

**LoginController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public function redirectTo() {
        $isAuth = Auth::check();

        if ($isAuth) {
            return redirect('dashboard');
        } else {
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) 
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::resource('project','ProjectController');
Route::resource('client','ClientController');
Route::resource('task','TaskController');
Route::resource('people','PeopleController');

Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your `Auth::routes()` before your first route

```
 <?php

Auth::routes()

Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('home');
 });
```

And use `auth` middleware in your controllers where you want only authenticated user.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a middleware for that. To get info on what a middleware is check here laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

Let's see how you can use the default Laravel's auth middleware for this purpose:

First of all get rid of your AdminBaseController and use only AdminController

Then you have to check that the auth middleware is enabled in the file app\Http\Kernel.php

You should have the line:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

This means that the middleware is active and usable for your routes.

Now let's go inside the middleware class in app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php to specify the middleware's behaviour :

this method will be triggered before your controller constructor

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //check here if the user is authenticated
    if ( ! $this->auth->user() )
    {
        // here you should redirect to login 
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now the only thing left to do is to decide for what routes you should apply the middleware. Let's suppose you have two routes that you want to be only accessible from authenticated users, you should specify to use the middleware for these two routes in this way:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth' ], function()
{
    Route::get('admin/home', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did what you said and added that bit of code into Authenticate.php, but when I try to go to route I specified I get the following error:    ```"Declaration of App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, App\Http\Middleware\Closure $next) should be compatible with Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)   ```                                                                                                                                             Also this happens even when I'm authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Move your `Auth:Routes();` right after

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

Then all your routes will be auth protected.